# Add conditional breakpoint in Intellij without gutter

Tags: intellij-idea

I prefer not to display gutter icons - they are to me simply distracting. However, I may need to do so (?) for `Conditional Breakpoints` ?

There does not seem to be any action available for *Add Conditional Breakpoint* ..  The following reference - along with others viewed - only refer to *right clicking* on the red *breakpoint* gutter icon.. None mention a menu / keyboard action for same.  Did I miss it?

https://www.eviltester.com/2016/08/convert-breakpoint-into-conditional.html

[image]

*Update* : Here are the options for `breakpoint` from `Actions` popup dialog - none speak to me as being related to `conditional breakpoint':

My version is `Ultimate 2018.3`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on Mac) and type "breakpoint".

You'll find two actions named "Toggle line breakpoint" (allowing to add or remove a breakpoint), and "Edit breakpoint" (allowing to edit the breakpoint you added, to add a condition for example).

Note: The "Edit breakpoint" action only appears if there is a breakpoint to edit on that line.

Comment: hi:  which version ?  I pasted the "breakpoint" options in the OP now: do not see an applicable `conditional` action

Comment: The latest version (2018.3.3)

Comment: Do you have a different list than shown in the updated OP?  There is no `Edit breakpoint` there. Ah - it is  *`View`* breakpoint.  I will award but please correct the answer.

Comment: It's definitaly "Edit breakpoint" here. But the action only appears if you have a breakpoint already on the line where the cursor is: you can't edit a breakpoint that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+SHIFT+F8 opens a dialog where you can create new or edit existing breakpoints without touching the gutter. 
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html